# classic table footnote with a twist

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{footnote}

\makesavenoteenv{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
  \hline
  foo\footnote{fuz} & bar
  \hline
 \end{tabularx}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I like the formating of the `tabularx` environemnt. However, it does not allow for the choice of positioning of the table (to the best of my knowledge). My understaning is that `tabularx` produces the footnote (which I tested), but on the other hand, `table` traps them, therefore I sought  to `\usepackage{footnote}` and `\makesavenoteenv{table}`. What is wrong with my reasoning.

One more caveat: I need to `hyperref` the `\footnote`s

**EDIT**: The positioing of the footmark is unimporant. And preferably no hacks like `\footnotemark`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't at all clear from your question where you want the footnote text to appear, but I think you want it within the float below the `tabularx`. The standard LaTeX markup to get in-float footnotes is

```
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
....
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

`minipage` displays all footnotes in scope at the end of the environment.

Comment: sorry I do not know what you mean. What do you want to position, and what does not allow that?

Comment: @aiao why do you think that the optional argument of `table` is affected by the content of the table environment? It is not. You can use `[htp]` with the code in this answer.